# Component ID j_id?:name has already been found in the view

Tags: jsf, duplicates

i have error HTTP Status 500 in my project. i am using integration of jsf spring and hibernate. i have no idea to solve this problem.
i have added the necessary jar files.
the error is:

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Component ID j_idt4:name has already been found in the view.  
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
```

the trace is:

```
</head>
<body>
<h1>اضافه کردن پرسنل جد?د</h1>

  +id: j_idt4
   type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@1810af25
    +id: j_idt5
     type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@cc4dacd
      +id: j_idt6
       type: 
              شماره پرسنل? : 

      +id: name
       type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@6f5ab27a
```

personel.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>اطلاعات پرسنلی</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>اضافه کردن پرسنل جدید</h1>
        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="6" dir="rtl">
              شماره پرسنلی : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personelMB.personel_id}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="id" >
                </h:inputText>
                نام : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personelMB.pname}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="Name" >
                </h:inputText>

                 نام خانوادگی: 
                <h:inputText id="family" value="#{personelMB.pfamily}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="family" >
                </h:inputText> 

                آدرس : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="address" value="#{personelMB.paddress}" 
                    cols="30" rows="10" required="true"
                    label="Address" >
                </h:inputTextarea>


          تلفن:  
                <h:inputText id="tel" value="#{personelMB.pphone}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="tel" >
                </h:inputText> 
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="درج اطلاعات" action="#{personelMB.addPersonel()}" />

        </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me.

Comment: Sami you can also use "label" in h:inputText as it will provide clear error message like "Component ID **Name** has already been found in the view." instead of some values like Component ID j_idt4:name. Further j_idt4 is name of your form which is throwing this error, you can also provide "id" to form to have clear understanding which form's content is throwing error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two occurences of `<h:inputText` with `id="name"`. Those `id`s ought to be unique  within the closest parent component that is a naming container, such as a data table component, or a form.